# MySQL: WHERE sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta consulta en un servidor remoto con PHP para el inicio de sesión:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    empleado
WHERE
    celular = '9' AND clave = '$clave';
```

Sin embargo, para evitar problemas quisiera que todo se compare ya sea en mayúsculas o minúsculas. Su ayudaría lo valoraré mucho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podemos resolver esto así:

```
select * 
from empleados 
where celular = '9' and
lower(clave) = lower('Xx');
```

En esta consulta transformamos el contenido del **campo clave** y el valor con el que se está comparando a minúscula utilizando la **función lower**(También puede ser mayúscula, **función upper**), de esta forma hacemos que ambos (campo y valor comparado) normalicen su formato y entonces verificamos si son iguales o no.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza esas dos funciones:

- UPPER para mayúsculas
- LOWER para minúsculas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Barry503, gracias por responder. Sería ideal que añadieses un enlace de referencia a la página de donde tomaste esa captura de pantalla. También es bueno añadir las descripciones en formato texto porque las imágenes no siempre se ven bien. Lee [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Para las minusculas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
where celular = '9' and
lower(clave) = lower('Xx');
```

Y paras las mayusculas:

```
where celular = '9' and
lower(clave) = UPPER('Xx');
```

Espero haberte ayudado .